# Why can't I access memory at $eax or $rax using x/3x

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, gdb

*disclaimer* I'm new to assembly so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question and my terminology and everything are bad.

The following code, I believe, is an x86 representation of a linked list. I am doing the "binary bomb" project and have been following a walkthrough for a different bomb to give me an idea of the steps I should take. I was able to access the information for $rax with the command **x/3x $rax**. Based on the assembly code and the address given in the error I can tell it is storing a node which points to next node in the list located at *($rax+8). For some reason however when I try to look at that location my terminal tells me it cannot access the memory at that location. Why might this be? What am I doing wrong?

the errors themselves are located at the bottom of the assembly code. Not sure if its even possible to extrapolate any answers from what I've given but if it is, I'd love to solve the puzzle on my own, so please limit answers to just why I cannot access the memory at the given location.
Thanks!

```
    0x00000000004010bc <+0>:    push   %r13
  0x00000000004010be <+2>:  push   %r12
       0x00000000004010c0 <+4>: push   %rbp
       0x00000000004010c1 <+5>: push   %rbx
       0x00000000004010c2 <+6>: sub    $0x58,%rsp
       0x00000000004010c6 <+10>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
       0x00000000004010cb <+15>:    callq  0x401576 <read_six_numbers>
       0x00000000004010d0 <+20>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%r12
       0x00000000004010d5 <+25>:    mov    $0x0,%r13d
       0x00000000004010db <+31>:    jmp    0x401103 <phase_6+71>
       0x00000000004010dd <+33>:    callq  0x401540 <explode_bomb>
       0x00000000004010e2 <+38>:    jmp    0x401112 <phase_6+86>
       0x00000000004010e4 <+40>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
       0x00000000004010e7 <+43>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
       0x00000000004010ea <+46>:    jg     0x4010ff <phase_6+67>
       0x00000000004010ec <+48>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
       0x00000000004010ef <+51>:    mov    0x30(%rsp,%rax,4),%eax
       0x00000000004010f3 <+55>:    cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
       0x00000000004010f6 <+58>:    jne    0x4010e4 <phase_6+40>
       0x00000000004010f8 <+60>:    callq  0x401540 <explode_bomb>
       0x00000000004010fd <+65>:    jmp    0x4010e4 <phase_6+40>
       0x00000000004010ff <+67>:    add    $0x4,%r12
       0x0000000000401103 <+71>:    mov    %r12,%rbp
       0x0000000000401106 <+74>:    mov    (%r12),%eax
       0x000000000040110a <+78>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
       0x000000000040110d <+81>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
       0x0000000000401110 <+84>:    ja     0x4010dd <phase_6+33>
       0x0000000000401112 <+86>:    add    $0x1,%r13d
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
       0x0000000000401116 <+90>:    cmp    $0x6,%r13d
       0x000000000040111a <+94>:    je     0x40114f <phase_6+147>
       0x000000000040111c <+96>:    mov    %r13d,%ebx
       0x000000000040111f <+99>:    jmp    0x4010ec <phase_6+48>
       0x0000000000401121 <+101>:   mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
       0x0000000000401125 <+105>:   add    $0x1,%eax
       0x0000000000401128 <+108>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
       0x000000000040112a <+110>:   jne    0x401121 <phase_6+101>
       0x000000000040112c <+112>:   mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,8)
       0x0000000000401130 <+116>:   add    $0x1,%rsi
       0x0000000000401134 <+120>:   cmp    $0x6,%rsi
       0x0000000000401138 <+124>:   je     0x401156 <phase_6+154>
       0x000000000040113a <+126>:   mov    0x30(%rsp,%rsi,4),%ecx
       0x000000000040113e <+130>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
       0x0000000000401143 <+135>:   mov    $0x6042f0,%edx
       0x0000000000401148 <+140>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
       0x000000000040114b <+143>:   jg     0x401121 <phase_6+101>
       0x000000000040114d <+145>:   jmp    0x40112c <phase_6+112>
       0x000000000040114f <+147>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
       0x0000000000401154 <+152>:   jmp    0x40113a <phase_6+126>
       0x0000000000401156 <+154>:   mov    (%rsp),%rbx
       0x000000000040115a <+158>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
       0x000000000040115f <+163>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
       0x0000000000401163 <+167>:   mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdx
       0x0000000000401168 <+172>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
       0x000000000040116c <+176>:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
       0x0000000000401171 <+181>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
       0x0000000000401175 <+185>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
       0x000000000040117a <+190>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
       0x000000000040117e <+194>:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
       0x0000000000401183 <+199>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
       0x0000000000401187 <+203>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
       0x000000000040118f <+211>:   mov    $0x5,%ebp
       0x0000000000401194 <+216>:   jmp    0x40119f <phase_6+227>
       0x0000000000401196 <+218>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
       0x000000000040119a <+222>:   sub    $0x1,%ebp
       0x000000000040119d <+225>:   je     0x4011b0 <phase_6+244>
       0x000000000040119f <+227>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
       0x00000000004011a3 <+231>:   mov    (%rax),%eax
       0x00000000004011a5 <+233>:   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
       0x00000000004011a7 <+235>:   jle    0x401196 <phase_6+218>
       0x00000000004011a9 <+237>:   callq  0x401540 <explode_bomb>
       0x00000000004011ae <+242>:   jmp    0x401196 <phase_6+218>
       0x00000000004011b0 <+244>:   add    $0x58,%rsp
       0x00000000004011b4 <+248>:   pop    %rbx
       0x00000000004011b5 <+249>:   pop    %rbp
       0x00000000004011b6 <+250>:   pop    %r12
       0x00000000004011b8 <+252>:   pop    %r13
       0x00000000004011ba <+254>:   retq   
    End of assembler dump.
    (gdb) x/3x $rax
    0x604950 <input_strings+400>:   0x20342036  0x20352031  0x00322033
    (gdb) x/3x *($rax+8)
    0x322033:   Cannot access memory at address 0x322033
    (gdb) x/3x *($rax + 8)
    0x322033:   Cannot access memory at address 0x322033
```

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the memory pointed to by `rax` just fine with `x/3x $rax`.  (So your question title is wrong).

You have 2 problems with `x/3x *($rax+8)`:

1. the memory pointed to by RAX looks like ASCII characters.  (Try `x /16c $rax`, or `p (char*)$rax`.)  It *doesn't* look like a valid address.  (You could look at `less /proc/$(pidof my_bomb)/maps` to find what virtual address ranges your target process has mapped.)
2. You're only using 32 bits of data as an address.  GDB doesn't have type information for asm or registers in general, and typically defaults to `int` or `int*`.  In this case, `$rax+8` is treated as an `int*` in `*($rax+8)`, so you're asking GDB to take 4 bytes of memory as the argument to the `x` command.

x86-64 pointers are 64 bits long, so you should have been using `x /3xg` to dump 3 x86 qwords (which GDB calls "`g`iant", not the default 32-bit GDB `w`ord.  Note that GDB's terminology matches a typical 32-bit RISC machine, not x86 terminology even when debugging x86 targets).

`0x00322033` is unlikely to be the low 32 bits of a valid address where you'd find another pointer in compiler-generated code, because it's odd.  The x86-64 System V ABI aligns 64-bit pointers / integers to 64 bits by default, so the start of a struct containing pointers will be at an address that's divisible by 8 (ends with `8` or `0` in hex).

**But if `$rax+8` was an 8-byte pointer with some non-zero values in the upper 32, you could `x /3xg *(void **)($rax+8)` or something**, so the expression you're dereferencing has pointer-to-pointer type and thus will load a whole pointer's worth of data.

Alternatively, you could copy/paste the address from the previous `x` command.  Or you can use a `print` command.  For example, at `_start` in a process (so `rsp+8` is `argv[0]`):

```
(gdb) p $rsp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe690
(gdb) p *(void**)($rsp+8)
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe9c5

(gdb) p **(void**)($rsp+8)       # oops, always need at least one more * in the type and in the deref
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.

(gdb) p **(long**)($rsp+8)
$5 = 7955998172649846063
(gdb) p /x **(long**)($rsp+8)   # same value, different format (/x isn't default because it's an integer type, not a pointer)
$6 = 0x6e69622f7273752f

(gdb) p  **(void*****)($rsp+8)     # you can use a zillion *s in the type :P

$7 = (void ***) 0x6e69622f7273752f      # this wasn't a linked list!
(gdb) p  ***(void*****)($rsp+8)
Cannot access memory at address 0x6e69622f7273752f   # ASCII data as a pointer is bogus
```